# lldb - How to overwrite a value in a dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, lldb

So I'm debugging an app remotely with lldb (no Xcode) and there is a value in a dictionary I want to modify. 
The dictionary looks like this when I do 'po $x0':

```
{
    amount = "2.00";
    idNumber = 87677;
}
```

When I print the 'class' of 2.00 I get NSDecimalNumber
I've tried getting access to it and was able to read just the 'amount' value:

```
po [$x0 objectForKey:@"amount"]
2.95
```

I want to be able to overwrite the amount value to 1.00 -- I tried doing this:

```
e (NSString*)[$x0 objectForKey:@"amount"]
(NSString *) $24 = 0x00000001c2c22180
(lldb) memory write 0x00000001c2c22180 @"1.00"
error: '@1.00' is not a valid hex string value.
(lldb) memory write 0x00000001c2c22180 "1.00"
error: '1.00' is not a valid hex string value.
```

How can I write an NSdecimal number to the 'amount' field?
It won't let me simply do $x0[@"amount"] = 1.00
Thank you!

EDIT: I've also just tried this:

```
(lldb) p/x 0.10
(NSTaggedPointerString *) $26 = 0xa00000030312e304 @"0.10"
(lldb) memory write 0x00000001c2c22180 0xa00000030312e304
error: Value 0xa00000030312e304 is too large to fit in a 1 byte 
unsigned integer value.
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a breakpoint, In xcode debugger console. type `expr` to over-write a value.

For example if you want to over write a integer with value (100) to (200).

```
expr integer = 200
```

Same you can do it with dictionary like:

```
expr dictionary[@"key"] = @"newvalue"
```